# How to add a button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, button

Im using ajax to render a table on my page. In the last row of the table Im trying to display a button which is handling my "edit" function like so:

```
$(".editPersonnel").on("click", function () {
$("#editPersonnelModal").modal("show");
$tr = $(this).closest("tr");

var data = $tr
  .children("td")
  .map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
  })
  .get();

$("#idPer").val(data[0]);
$("#updateLastName").val(data[1]);
$("#updateFirstName").val(data[2]);
$("#updateJobTitle").val(data[3]);
$("#updateEmail").val(data[4]);
$("#updateDepartment").val(data[5]);
$("#updateLocation").val(data[6]);
console.log(data);
```

});

Im trying to render that button using jQuery but when I do this:

```
 $("<td>").html(
             '<td><button class="btn btn-info editPersonnel">Edit</button>'
            )
```

the button shows on the page but doesn't work.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Im still such a newbie...
Thanks!

Comment: Side Note: you have an extra leading `<td>` when trying to append to a `<td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use event delegation since the elements are dynamically created.

```
// Replace document with nearest static parent/ancestor, if possible
$(document).on("click", ".editPersonnel", function (){
   // ...
});
```

Comment: That reads the data but the modal still doesn't show for some reason?

Comment: Or maybe it shows but its under my current modal. Ill  be back in a sec!

Comment: Yep, that works, modal shows under opened modal! Thanks for help!

Comment: @ChiChiHuang Glad to help.